# How to execute external PHP script using Laravel Commands?

Tags: php, laravel, shell, command, command-line-interface

I have created several `php` scripts (not Laravel) and I put it inside the `app/cli` folder of my Laravel project. Inside `cli` folder I have `php` files like:

- fileConverter.php

  - fileUploader.php
  - fileDownloader.php

Now I have created an artisan command that will be executed by `php artisan runFileManager` line.

My problem is, how to execute those scripts inside the `handle()` function

```
public function handle()
    {
        // How to execute external php files here?
    }
```

of my command class?

Comment: Cant you just include them?

Answer (score 0):

You could simple call

```
include base_path('app/cli/fileConverter.php');
```

Just make sure your file/s [fileConverter.php,..etc] are self dependent